# I am adding three image button and I want it to be in bottom center so that it suitable for all device

Tags: android

I have three `ImageButton` objects. I don't know how to make it suitable for
all device when I'm using in big screen phone the button coming in
left side please help. I want to set it in bottom and in the  middle for all small and big device

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.nmohdibraralam.mainmenu.Drawer"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_drawer">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:background="@drawable/niral13"/>



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/niral1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="3" >


        <ImageButton android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/round"

            android:id="@+id/abtus"
            android:src="@drawable/abuot"
            />
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/round"

        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:src="@drawable/menu"
      />


    <ImageButton android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/round"

        android:id="@+id/reg"
        android:src="@drawable/rgtr"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using linearlayout and you can achieve this using weight.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.nmohdibraralam.mainmenu.Drawer"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_drawer" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/niral13" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/niral1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/abtus"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/round"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/abuot" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu"
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/round"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/menu" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/reg"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/round"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/rgtr" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can also add two `Space` views using weight between the `ImageView`s, getting you the spacing without having to wrap the `ImageView`s in an extra layout.

Comment: ok...Thanks its  worked... One more thing the  imageview id img1 which I am giving margin left and top . How will i set it to the top center

Comment: What do you mean by "top center"? Did you mean vertically center or horizontally or both?